# Multisite setup on Centos 7 Drupal commerce site

Tags: drupal, multisite, drupal-commerce

I have requirement of Drupal project which is a commerce website. We have used Drupal commerce module for the same purpose before.

I have Centos 7 as my server with EasyApache installed. Everything is installed on the server to run Drupal project and normal Drupal project is working nice.

I have tried to make multisite working for my website. Tried many options:

- Added subsite under sites folder (example.com)
- Added site link in sites.php file ($sites['example.co'] = 'example.co';)
- Created virtual host and symlink
- And many more..

There are too many finding for multisite on Google but none of them is working well for me.
Can someone help me to configure multisite on centos 7 server?

Comment: Hi did you adding the site to vhost and enabled it? Did you have checked the /var/log/apache2... can you tail and check there what happening, regards. This website is  a dedicate hosting?

Comment: Yup i added vhost. Enabled it too. There is no error on log files. Its cloud hosting.

Comment: Witch version Drupal are you using? did you adding the new host on the site configuration and to the file drupal/web/sites/default/settings.php?

Comment: Drupal7. I am not sure for host in site conf and settings.php

Also i want to add one thing. New domain(example.com) is pointing to default page even after all settings till now.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your domain.com/web/sites/default/settings.php add your host like this :

```
 $settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
     '^example\.co$',
     '^www.example\.co$',
 );
```

On linux if you can't due of rights to set it, just change the rights of folder parent and the file.

```
sudo chmod 777 default
sudo chmod 777 settings.php
```

After the fix you can reverse to rights by :

```
sudo chmod 555 default
sudo chmod 444 settings.php
```

On the admin site you need to set it too and at first time if didn't do it.

Comment: I have added give code to my settings.php file. Still not able to make it working.

Comment: @Arpi Patel this is a fresh install? or you did an install from a based on an old one with a different domain?

Comment: Its fresh installed

Comment: @Arpi Patel This is also a sysadmin issue :(, if you can see the site, if you didn't got any error from apaches, mysql, or php from error.log. i guess you hosting settings need some adding info. Did you use cache? did you cleared the cache after any change? i need so info also an error is a way to work but in your context ????